# Logstash / GROK: Creating a custom Variable when parsing a log file

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, logstash-grok, grok

I am new to Grok, although I have managed to create custom regular expressions and write GROK filters in the logstash config file. My problem is as follows:

**SOURCE FIELD** - 
 I am parsing a log file, where, every event includes a 'source' field, which is the name of the log file, e.g.:

```
test.YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.log
```

**What I want to do is**: For each event, where 'source' contains this filename, extract the date and time in the following format within a new field within the Grok Filter:

```
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

I know how to write custom Regular Expressions (REs) in GROK, but I cannot write an RE which will match the data *and* format it before storing it into a variable. So that is my problem.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you need match the data and format it before storing it. How about matching it and then adding a new variable or replacing an old one with the [mutate filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html)

Comment: The trouble is that the application logs I am parsing, contain the Start TimeStamp as the first line in the file, e.g. "start: YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS". And I don't know a how to use the mutate syntax to create a global variable.

Comment: What I asked above was the second option, which I thought might be easy, that is, to extract/manipulate the Start Timestamp from the Log file's name.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the date from the filename should work. You should be able to match the date parts in the source field with a grok filter and add a new field like so:

```
filter { 
    grok {
        match => [
        "source", "test.%{YEAR:year}%{MONTHNUM2:month}%{DATA:day}_%{HOUR:hour}%{MINUTE:minute}%{SECOND:second}.log"
        ]
    }
    mutate { add_field => { "your_new_date_field" => "%{day}/%{month}/%{year} %{hour}:%{minute}:%{second}" } }
}
```

I don't have the possibility to test this right now but I hope you get the idea.

This solution will create a lot of additional fields like year, month, day and so on. If you want to get rid of the additional fields you can use [metadata fields](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-metadata).